# How use plugin in phonegap for change screen orientation?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, screen-orientation

My phonegap app should run in portrait orientation. Only one page (index.html) should run in landscape mode. Then I found the plugin for this, but doesn't work for me.

`cordova plugin add net.yoik.cordova.plugins.screenorientation`

In config.xml:

`<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />`

Index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>App</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script>
var so = cordova.plugins.screenorientation;
so.setOrientation(so.Orientation.LANDSCAPE);
</script>
```

For android, the application returns an error `App has stopped`.

For iPhone, nothing happening.

Comment: show me your error msg?

Comment: [phonegap] [console.log] Channel not fired: onNativeReady [phonegap] [console.log] Channel not fired: onPluginsReady [phonegap] [console.log] Channel not fired: onCordovaReady

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this script first

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Then inside another script tag

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady()
    {

       var so = cordova.plugins.screenorientation;
       so.setOrientation(so.Orientation.LANDSCAPE);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help… The code return errors. [phonegap] [console.log] Channel not fired: onNativeReady
[phonegap] [console.log] Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
[phonegap] [console.log] Channel not fired: onCordovaReady

Comment: You can help me? @AtanuCSE

Comment: I can't think of any other problem. The codes I provided should work if plugin code is okay.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are using the old API which existed prior to v1.0.  Maybe you found the example on an old blog post?

In any case see the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation). Using the current API it will look like: (must be after device ready)

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady()
    {
        screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
    }
</script>
```